# Redirect old ASP page to new ASP.net page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, redirect

I had a page named www.mysite.com/page.asp. That page does not exist anymore and I want it to go to www.mysite.com/type/newpage.aspx when a user clicks on the old link. Any ideas ?

Comment: Where does the old link exists, in which page?

Comment: In this page "www.mysite.com/page.asp"  have one line of code   response.redirect "www.mysite.com/type/newpage.aspx".  Any one arriving at the old page will automatically be sent to the new page.  IIS and ASP.net may also offer some other solutions but this is a Classic ASP solution.

Comment: the old asp page has been deleted it does not exist. @Dee

Comment: You could just create a page with that name and put the one line of code in it.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

if you have hosted your application on IIS, you can perform an URL rewrite to redirect to the new page. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Assuming that it's IIS7 or later.  If you're still on IIS6 you need to look at third party solutions

Comment: I don't have permission to go into IIS and do this. What other option do I have ?

Comment: There's a very good chance that the module will already be installed on your webserver.  If you can't access IIS manager you can add rewrite rules directly in your web.config file